# ConnectivityManager do not work on Motorola xoom (honeycomb 3.2)

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, motorola-droid

I have a method call `isNetworkAvailable()`
to check if the user have enable wap/wifi/wimax this works for Android 2.1 to 2.3+.

But now a user of the app which uses honeycomb 3.2 on a Motorola xoom
rapport to me that he can´t open the app.

In my android developer web-interface I can see this log-error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/811881/

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable()
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connec.getNetworkInfo(0);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connec.getNetworkInfo(1);
    NetworkInfo wimaxInfo = connec.getNetworkInfo(6);
    if (wimaxInfo!=null) {
        return mobileInfo.isConnected() || wifiInfo.isConnected()|| wimaxInfo.isConnected();
    }
    else {
        return mobileInfo.isConnected() || wifiInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

#### See the whole Class/Activity here(line 276):

https://github.com/voidcode/Diaspora-Webclient/blob/master/src/com/voidcode/diasporawebclient/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mobileInfo or wifiInfo could be null. On a wifi-only device I wouldn't be surprised if mobileInfo (ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) is null.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem with Motorola Xoom, because it does not have connectivity support for `ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE`.

The following code is working fine for me:

```
ConnectivityManager connMngr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
try { 
    return connMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected(); 
} catch (NullPointerException npe) { 
    return false; 
}
```